# Android kotlin - upload image with Volley error: Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

```
fun UploadToServer(klein: Bitmap, mitte: Bitmap){

        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        klein.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos)
        val imageBytes = baos.toByteArray()
        val imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)


        val request = object:StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.xxxx.com/uploadimage.php", object: Response.Listener<String> {
            override fun onResponse(response: String) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                Log.d("letsSee", "Success! JSON: " + response)
            }
        }, object: Response.ErrorListener {
            override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError:VolleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@UploadImage, "Some error occurred -> " + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }) {
            protected val params:Map<String, String>

                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                get() {
                    val parameters = HashMap<String, String>()
                    parameters.put("klein", imageString)
                    return parameters
                }

        }
        val rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@UploadImage)
        rQueue.add(request)

    }
```

[image]

What is this and what do I need to do here? I'm starting to regret using Kotlin even though Java is plain disgusting. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh wait I see what you're doing. Hang on.

Comment: This is inside the UploadToServer fun. I try to add what is missed, I couldn't because stackoverflow is bitching about "too much code not enough text" -.-

Comment: Ok now it's complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
    val parameters = HashMap<String, String>()
    parameters.put("klein", imageString)
    return parameters
}
```

Kotlin has two forms of the Map object: Map and MutableMap. MutableMap is equal to Java's Map, while Map is Kotlin's own thing.

Comment: @donkinged your stuff is what you current have in the params get() block.

Comment: Ok I pasted it there now but still get all kind of stupid errors no matter what I do. I need the whole code because I don't understand ANYTHING here

Comment: But now these errors: override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> : Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getParams()Ljava/util/Map;): and override val params is still 'params' overrides nothing

Comment: Try `override protected fun getParams()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Change `params` to `parameter` after val keyword.** kotlin automatically create get method for variable and you declared `params`, so the getter method will be `getParams` which is conflicting with predefined method.

Comment: OP is trying to override `getParams()`, not make another method.

Comment: ok the error is gone BUT, why the hell is the first parameters val "Property "parameters" is never used" and when I remove it I get all kind of strange errors afterwards. It's failing to send image

Comment: I've seen countless "totorials" how to upload image now but they all are either broken/outdated or the code is 10000 lines. Can someone show me a proper tutorial? I'm desperate with this crap

Comment: You can use this pretty awesome library which makes your http calls easy:
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking